# bash autocomplete personal command : cannot autocomplete the argument after the option

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I wrote the autocomplete function for my command, but it is not autocomplete the argument after the option flag

```
function _qpdm_complete() 
{
    local cur prev options my_list
    COMPREPLY=()

    cur="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    options="-opt" 
    my_list="quantum alpha betta omega operation"   

    if [[ ${cur} == -* || ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" ${cur}) )
        return 0
    else 
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${my_list}" -- ${cur}) )
    fi
}

complete -F _qpdm_complete qpdm
```

then in terminal

qpdm <TAB>

```
qpdm -opt
```

qpdm -opt<TAB>

```
qpdm -opt  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

qpdm -opt o<TAB>

expecting

```
qpdm -opt o
omega operation
```

but get

```
qpdm -opt o  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

What is missed in my _qpdm_complete()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just a typo: `COMP_WORD` is not a variable used by Bash (or, at least, I am unable to find it in the manual). You should have written [`COMP_WORDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COMP_005fWORDS) instead.

In your code, both `cur` and `prev` are always empty because `${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD]}` and `${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD-1]}` refer to an undefined variable. And `compgen`, correctly, always returns all the option values that match an empty `cur`.

Comment: It works! Thanks.
Just another tiny question: How can I prevent that after "qpdm -opt omega <TAB>" it is not respond with "qpdm -opt omega -opt"  but stop the completion process?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. For instance, you may add `if [[ $COMP_CWORD -gt 2 ]]; then return 0; ...` as the first test (before or at the beginning of the `if` block you already have).

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!